# Will saved CFD/CAD projects on HDD affect speed even if program is installed at SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, speed, cad

Programs are install on SSD.

If I want increase lifetime of SSD because of to much writing and save projects on HDD, is this good idea or will affect speed too much?
What are pros & cons of saved projects on HDD vs SSD?

My SSD is 500GB, HDD 5TB , and CFD projects can be 100GB+..SSD has 150TBW  and it is not so cheap as HDD.

Comment: You purchased the SSD for its speed.  USE IT.  You will replace the computer long before the SSD wears out.

Comment: You're more than a decade too late with such concerns.

Comment: @Keltari But SSD is more expensive than HDD, i dont have money for 5TB SSD and CFD projects can be 100GB+

Comment: It's irrelevant. Again, *You will replace the computer long before the SSD wears out* and you'll replace it because obsolete, in a nutshell. This question is the same of all other previous ones, it either stems from a very poor understanding or paranoia. If the latter the help you need isn't here; if the former then why are you wasting other users' time and effort if you don't accept answers/comments?

Comment: @user707264 what you have to ask is whether your time waiting for the HDD to serve up 100GB is more or less expensive than the SSD. At the very least you should be benchmarking a couple of representative projects on both the HDD and SSD to find out just how much time is saved or wasted. If the data takes 5 hours to be crunched by your computer and the SSD makes no difference then there is no use in your case. If the SSD reduces the time from 4 hours to 30 minutes then it's up to you to justify the cost of that time and whether the added productivity is worth it. We cannot decide for you.

Comment: @Mokubai If SSD has 300TBW and I working with 300GB+ projects than it is very easy to calculate how many years will SSD last. Isnt it?

Comment: And that would be a firm number you can calculate. Are you rewriting that amount of data every single day or are you writing it once a month and then reading it with only minor writes for the next month? We have no idea of your datasets and their usage patterns.  If an SSD saves you a significant amount of time then it could justify the cost in increased productivity and output. But you're not asking us about the drive TBW, you are asking for vague "pros and cons" and whether it will affect something you've told us nearly no details of. The only person who can say if it is worth it is you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have this issue reversed.

Yes, using a hard drive to get Program Data when the Program is on an SSD will take some extra time. If the HDD is already spinning, not much time.

But a good SSD has a TBW capacity (Tera Bytes Written) normally beyond the life of the machine.

Just use your SSD and that will be fine.  SSDs today are very reliable, more so now then most HDDs.

I have not used a HDD on any machine including desktop machines since 2013.

The other benefit of SSDs in any computer is lower power consumption. My desktop and laptop computers average less than 15 watts of power.

Comment: My SSD is 500GB, HDD 5TB , and CFD projects can be 100GB+.. What you suggest now?

Comment: 500 GB is normally enough for most things.  I have almost that much in virtual machines on my SSD fitting well within 500 GB .  Check  but you should be fine.

Comment: But if just one CFD project can be 100GB+ than I cant save my projects on SSD..So what  is your suggestion?

Comment: You can do 2 things:   As noted a decent HDD is adequate for data storage.  Or, add a second 500 GB or larger SSD.

Comment: Why then exist PC/workstations with HDD and SSD? Follow your logic, HDD dont have any purpose?

Comment: My own Desktop machine has two Samsung SSDs (3 TB in total).  No hard drives any more

Comment: If SSD has 300TBW and you work with projects of 300GB then this SSD will not last long... Isnt it?

Comment: 300 TBW is a lot of data writes. That will last a long time.

Comment: The other thing to note, is that the program will load fast from SSD, but once loaded it will stay in memory.  Thats generally not the slow part.  Its the reading and writing of data - THATS the slow part.  It will be SIGNIFICANTLY faster loading and saving 100G+ from the SSD than the disk.